# select where number combination matches part of integer SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

Assuming a simple one but Im looking up a customer ID ie: 930566615552 and only have the last 8 digits 66615552 - how would one do this?

I've attempted a WHERE RIGHT, LIKE and Cast the column as vachar but no avail.

I'm sure this question has been asked before, I know I'm just searching the wrong terms to find the answer!

Comment: Do you always have the last 8 digits? and what type is the id column?

Answer (score 2):

You could query

```
... WHERE CAST(id AS text) LIKE '%66615552'
```

Indexing for such a query would require a trigram index.

Answer (score 2):

there is modulus operator %

So

```
5 % 10 = 5
325 % 100 = 25
457322844 % 10000 = 2844
```

but it has caveats:

1. you need to specify correct base that will be dynamic in your case
2. it ignores index for this numeric column

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options if the column is an INT and you always have the last 8 digits of the id:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id % 100000000 = 66615552;
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE RIGHT(CAST(id AS TEXT), 8) = '66615552';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with right function:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE RIGHT(id, 8) = '66615552'
```

OR Use like operator

SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id, 8 like '%66615552'